# PHP delay execution for ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i am getting the user timezone  by the JavaScript.  and sending the ajax request to save that value in session so that i can use that value in the further logic. This is working fine but the settion value is available on the second page load. 
Is there any way to wait for the ajax response  and  start further execution when session variable will be available.

i am using the following the code for this

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var tz = jstz.determine(); 
        var timezone = tz.name(); 
        $.post("abc.php", {tz: timezone}, function(data) {
                 location.reload(); 
         });
      });
    </script>
 <?php
$timezonevalue=$_SESSION['timezone'];
?>
```

Now i am reloading the page after ajax request that is working fine but  that's create some interruption for the user . Is there any way to delay php execution until the session variable is available.

Comment: Totally unclear. Why wait for something?

Comment: undated the question please check

Comment: i am getting the session variable that is set through the ajax

Comment: use ``$post.done(callback)``

Comment: are you dealing with the same page?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , no i have multiple pages

Comment: but that check will be in the header so that available in the whole site

Comment: if there is no timezone data in session, load only this js code. It will be fast enough to don't delay page loading

Comment: Looks like you don't understand workflow. After your page is loaded to browser - all php codes are __already executed__. PHP is not executed step by step waiting for client events to happen. Server processed your request for page and forgot about you.

Comment: @u_mulder i am agreed with your comment. then what will be the alternative approach for this ?

Comment: The simpliest way is I think that @splash58 suggested. You load just a js-script, do ajax-request, then reload page with full data of timezone.

Comment: Another option is just load page with your script and as a response of ajax request you got all data for page.

Comment: @u_mulder going with your suggestion :)

Comment: Why are you even setting the time zone in a session? Simply send the time zone with **each** request, it's really not a lot of information to send. Your design is bad here and it's not doing you any favors, change your logic so that the problem can't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("abc.php", {tz: timezone}, function(data) {
                 location.reload(); 
 })
 .done(function(data){

     // here you are sure the request is done 


});
```

You can also add `.error(callback)`  if you want to keep track of errors.

Check jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for more details.

Comment: .done  is the alternative method what i am doing now . there is no difference in approach

Comment: @Mehar Then what is really your problem, cause i can't understand it ?

Comment: Then How you posted your answer if you didn't understand the problem ?

Comment: i've understood only the title of your question  :

*PHP delay execution for ajax response?*  and some words like these :
``Is there any way to wait for the ajax response`` from your question

Comment: @Mehar And apparently you want to ask for  **something else that is not expressed  in your question**